# Why are member variables captured by an "all automatic" capture, but not by explicit naming?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

In C++11 (from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)):

> [&] captures all automatic variables used in the body of the lambda by
>   reference and current object by reference if exists

And...

> [a,&b] where a is captured by copy and b is captured by reference

So my question is, if we have a class such as (VERSION A):

```
class Foo
{
    public:

    void test()
    {
        auto y = [&](){ return x; }();   // Line 6
    }

    int x;    
};
```

In Line 6, we successfully capture the member variable `x` using the "all automatic variables by reference" capture specifier.

Or we can write (VERSION B):

```
{
    int& x = this->x;
    auto y = [&x](){ return x; }();
}
```

But the following does not compile (VERSION C):

```
{
    auto y = [&x](){ return x; }();
}
```

This is because `x` does not exist as a name in the enclosing scope.

This also does not compile (VERSION D):

```
{
    auto y = [&this](){ return x; }();
}
```

This is because `this` cannot be captured by reference.

So, my question is, *why* does VERSION A work and not VERSION C or VERSION D? I understand why VERSION C and D do not work, but I don't understand why A works.

If we can't capture `this` by reference, and we cannot capture variables not in the parent scope, how is `x` being captured in VERSION A?

Intuitively, according to the capture rules VERSION B is the only version I'd expect to work.

Comment: Members are not really captured, but `this` is. you cannot do either `[&instance.x](){/*..*/}`.

Comment: In c++14, you can do things similar to `[x = this->x](){/*..*/}`.

Comment: Shouldn't the local variable `x` be a reference to make version B equivalent? `int& x = this->x;`

Comment: Thanks @lubgr, now updated the question to reflect this

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Version A works because `*this` is implicitly [captured](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture) by reference.

> The current object (*this) can be implicitly captured if either capture default is present.

When you specify capture default (the `[&]` in this case), `*this` is implicitly captured; which has the same effect as `[this]`. Note that what's captured by reference is `*this`, not `this` itself; `this` can't be captured explicitly by reference like `[&this]`, so version D fails.

Comment: Do you know _why_ disallowing an explicit capture of `this` make sense, when it can be implicitly captured by `[&]`?

Comment: Right, that's what I meant. Maybe it's simply inconsistent because `&this` looks like taking the address of a pointer, while `&*this` isn't much better?

Comment: @lubgr `&this` looks like you want to capture `this` itself by reference, and maybe you want to modify `this` pointer later? It's just invalid in capture.

Comment: Hm, for understanding, it might help to consider `this` always being passed by value as pointer? After all, we still need to dereference `this` even within the lambda (`[this]() { this->n = 7; }`)?

Comment: @songyuanyao I meant: **If** we use `this` within the lambda, we need to use it as `this->`, **not** as `this.`. That usage is optional/redundant is clear...

Comment: @songyuanyao Ok, thanks for the additional explanation.

Comment: @Aconcagua "`this` always being passed by value as pointer" was how the capture was described in the standard before capturing `*this` by copy (as `[*this]`) was introduced, but now it seems more consistent to describe `[this]` as capturing `*this` by reference.

Comment: @cpplearner Arguable... Generated machine code most likely won't show any difference between a reference to `*this` or `this` itself anyway. To understand *behaviour*, it appears easier to me to think of `this` being captured as pointer: `[=]`: `this` by value (still a pointer); `[&]`: `this` as reference (to const pointer; although not implemented as), `[this]` again by value (pointer), `[*this]` dereferenced pointer -> *object* by value, i. e. copy. Now with all this, it would rather appear to me consistent yet allowing `[&this]` (effectively equivalent to `[this]`, of course)...

Comment: @cpplearner About consistency: if a captured local variable `p` is a pointer itself, `[=]` captures by value, `[&]` by reference, so the pointer itself can be modified (sure, this still cannot, as pointer itself is const...). So no need to differentiate `this` and any other pointers... Going further: would appear consistent to allow capturing `[*p]` (pointee/object by value -> copy) as well...

Comment: @cpplearner Note from C++ standard (2017, 8.1.5.2.2: *"The form [&,this] is redundant but accepted for compatibility with ISO C++ 2014.
"* - this note gets obsolete with my considerations as well: all values passed by reference, `this` by value (as pointer); allowing this is consistent with allowing `[&, p]`, whereas `[=, this]` is dissallowed, again consistent with disallowing `[=, p]`...

Comment: I was intrigued by @lubgr's point about why explicit capture of `&*this` is not allowed, but it seems that `&*` is generally invalid, i.e. you can't do `&*x` either. @songyuanyao is it worth incorporating some of the points in the comments into the answer for a fuller answer?

Comment: @JamieBullock `&*x` is invalid in lambda capture, it just doesn't match the syntax, and the way how it's supposed to work. Which comment do you think to be helpful?